# Transfer a file in PHP

Tags: php, linux, rsync, scp

i have to transfer a created sql file from server a to server b. Currently i tried following without success:

```
// Some SQL executions to fill and update the tables
( .. )

// Filename pattern
$fileName = "dump_".date("Y-m-d-H_i_s").".sql";

// Dump the tables and saves the output in dump directory 
$dump = "mysqldump -u$USER -p$PASS $DB ".$this->dumpTables." > " . $this->path."dumps/". $fileName;

// Transfer the lastest sql file to the origin
$command = "scp " . $this->path."dbbackup/" . $fileName . " user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/PATH/dumps" . $fileName;

system($command, $retvalOrigin);
if ($retvalOrigin != 0) {
        fwrite($this->logFileInstance, $this->date() . "Something went wrong! \r\n");
        fwrite($this->logFileInstance, $this->date() . "$command! \r\n");
}
```

Whats the problem?

If i execute the command by hand, everything goes fine. So there is no permission problem. No unexpected log entries in my error log. If i copy the command without any vars and put this into a new php file, and call this, there is no error again.. 
At first i thougt scp hates me, thats why i replaced the "scp" with "rsync -ave". That gives me no error, but won't copy the file to the origin server (No error log again!).

scp -> $retvalOrigin = 1, no file on origin server, no error log

rsync -> $retvalOrigin = 0, no file on origin server, no error log

So what's the point?

Edit:

Path are ABSOLUTE, 
SSH KEY for the executing user and www-data - no login required anymore, 
$retVal includes ONLY 1 / 0,
and NO in won't use for that a cron

Comment: php.net says: `If the return_var argument is present, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.`. Most likely there is more information in the `$retvalOrigin`, try to `print_r` that value.

Comment: @Michiel it contains 1 / 0 - so it wont help me, would it? Other commands are okay, and give me the expected output (ls e.g.)

Comment: Ok, you can try adding the `-v` flag to the scp command, or try switching tot the `exec` command.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the user that uses the scp command (most likely www-data) has the permissions to use scp without authentification and not only your system user.

Also make sure that you use absolute paths.

For better error reporting use 'exec' for storing the error messages.
'system' will output the error directly and will get lost most likely when you use it in a cron.

```
exec($command, $commandOutput, $retvalOrigin);
```

Furthermore you can try shell_exec if the command needs a valid shell.

Comment: If i try to execute the SAME command in terminal everything goes fine.. Absoulte paths : CHECK! www-data and my user have all permissions to use rsync / scp. There is no password to enter, because the connecting user added a key - no auth required. Exec has same effect.

Comment: Is the ssh-key available to the www-data user?

Comment: The "www-data" user is not involved in this process. The user has the permission to read / write / append the file on both systems.. ssh-key is given, so no auth required.

Comment: then try to not only catch the return value but the output of the command. (like i edited in my post)

Comment: Yeah... no. I tried your edit. exec($command, $commandOutput, $retvalOrigin); -> $commandOutput is a empty array (whyever..) and $retvalOrigin is 1. It's awesome.

Comment: Did you redirect the output streams?
like $command .= ' 2>&1 ';
before you run the command.

The error stream of your command will not be written to stdout of the bash. With this redirect you can redirect the error stream to the output that will be received by php.